# android-how to retain dynamically added layout when app start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating LinearLayout dynamically (in another layout that contain two static EditText and ImageView) on Button click that contain EditText and ImageView. But when application start it will show nothing. So how to retain that LinearLayout. I have tried this. Thanks in Advance.

```
 public class HelpAlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public SharedPreferences sharedpreference;
LinearLayout add_new_layout, mainLayout, image_btn_layout, buttonLayout;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
Button btn_one, bt_submit;
MyEditText et_contact_one, et_contact_two, etAdd;
ImageView image_one, image_two;
ImageButton imageButton;
FloatingActionButton fab;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
List<MyEditText> allEds;
List<ImageView> allImg;
ImageView imageView;
String contactOne, contactTwo, number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7, number8, number9, number10, number11, number12, number13;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
private int counter = 0,many=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_alert);

    initialization();
}

private void initialization() {
    sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences("preference", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    editor = sharedpreference.edit();
    allEds = new ArrayList<>();
    allImg = new ArrayList<>();
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    image_btn_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_btn_layout);
    buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
    add_new_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    et_contact_one = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_one);
    et_contact_two = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_two);

    image_one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_one);
    image_two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_two);
    btn_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
    bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    image_one.setOnClickListener(this);
    image_two.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (sharedpreference != null) {
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image_btn_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image_btn_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    int no_of_layouts = sharedpreference.getInt("no_of_layouts",0);
    while(no_of_layouts>0){
        LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        LinearLayout childView = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        etAdd = generateEditText(counter);
        //add linear layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
       // imageView.setId(counter + 3);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        getValue(imageView);

        allEds.add(etAdd);
        allImg.add(imageView);
        childView.addView(etAdd);
        childView.addView(imageView);
        parentView.addView(childView);
        no_of_layouts--;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_one:
            if (this.counter < 10) {
                LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                LinearLayout childView = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                etAdd = generateEditText(counter);


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
                imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
                imageView.setId(counter + 3);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                getValue(imageView);

                allEds.add(etAdd);
                allImg.add(imageView);
                childView.addView(etAdd);
                childView.addView(imageView);
               parentView.addView(childView);

                counter++;
                many++;
                editor.putInt("no_of_layouts", many);

            } else {
               // v.setEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.image_one:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 1);
            break;
        case R.id.image_two:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 3);
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 4);
            break;
        case 5:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 5);
            break;
        case 6:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 6);
            break;
        case 7:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 7);
            break;
        case 8:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 8);
            break;
        case 9:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 9);
            break;
        case 10:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 10);
            break;
        case 11:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 11);
            break;
        case 12:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 12);
            break;
        case 13:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 13);
            break;
        case R.id.bt_submit:
            String ctone = et_contact_one.getText().toString();
            String ct_two = et_contact_two.getText().toString();
            int size = allEds.size();
            String[] strings = new String[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {

                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();

                editor.putString("contact" + i, strings[i]);
                Log.e("Added number", "" + i);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "contact" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (ctone.equals("") && ctone.isEmpty() || ct_two.equals("") && ct_two.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                editor.putString("contactOne", ctone);
                editor.putString("contactTwo", ct_two);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                //  }

                break;
            }
       case R.id.fab:
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image_btn_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}

private void getValue(ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String num = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                et_contact_one.setText(num);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number2 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                et_contact_two.setText(number2.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                number3 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number3.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number4 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number4.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number5 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number5.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number6 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number6.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number7 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number7.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number8 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number8.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number9 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number9.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number10 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number10.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                number11 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number11.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number12 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number12.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number13 = GetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number13.replaceAll("[- ]",""));
            }
            break;

    }

}

public MyEditText generateEditText(int id) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 90, 1.0f);
    layoutParams.setMargins(15, 10, 0, 0);
    MyEditText et = new MyEditText(this);
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(13)});
    et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_textfield_background);
    et.setHint("Enter or Select number");
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    et.setPadding(35, 0, 30, 0);
    et.setId(id);
    et.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return et;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    contactOne = sharedpreference.getString("contactOne", null);
    contactTwo = sharedpreference.getString("contactTwo", null);
    for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(sharedpreference.getString("contact" + i, "")+",");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    et_contact_one.setText(contactOne);
    et_contact_two.setText(contactTwo);
    int size = allEds.size();
    String[] strings = new String[size];
    String[] lines = stringBuilder.toString().split(",");
    for(String s : lines) {
        //  etAdd.setText(s);
     /*   strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
        sharedpreference.getString("contact" + i, "");*/
    }

}

/* public ImageView generateImageView(int id) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
    imageView.setId(id);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return imageView;
}*/
```

}

activity_help_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

     >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <a7colors.com.helpalert.CustomWidget.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxLength="13"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_textfield_background"
        android:hint="@string/contact_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_one"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/add_contact"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <a7colors.com.helpalert.CustomWidget.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxLength="13"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_textfield_background"
        android:hint="@string/contact_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_two"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/add_contact"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/image_btn_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/add_circular_button"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <a7colors.com.helpalert.CustomWidget.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bt_background"
        android:text="@string/btn_submit"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save a variable in `SharedPreference` when you have created that layout like below.

```
 case R.id.btn_one:
        if (this.counter < 10) {
            LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            LinearLayout childView = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            etAdd = generateEditText(counter);
            //add linear layout
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
            imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
            imageView.setId(counter + 3);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            getValue(imageView);

            allEds.add(etAdd);
            allImg.add(imageView);
            childView.addView(etAdd);
            childView.addView(imageView);
            parentView.addView(childView);
            counter++;
            many++;
            editor.putInt("no_of_layouts", many);
        } else {
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

The on activity initialisation check if this variable exists and if true, create that layout like below:

```
private void initialization() {
  sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences("preference", 
   Context.MODE_APPEND);
   editor = sharedpreference.edit();
   allEds = new ArrayList<>();
   allImg = new ArrayList<>();
   mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
   add_new_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
   et_contact_one = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_one);
   et_contact_two = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_two);
   image_one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_one);
   image_two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_two);
   btn_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
   bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
   image_one.setOnClickListener(this);
   image_two.setOnClickListener(this);
   btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);
   bt_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
   // adding layout if created
   int no_of_layouts = sharedpreference.getInt("no_of_layouts",0);
   while(no_of_layouts>0){
        // add whatever layout you have added before in onclick
    no_of_layout--;
   }

}
```

PS : I am assuming SharedPreference and clicking logic is working fine .
Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: SharedPreference and clicking logic is working fine .But when I open the app again it is showing me blank layout(that means already added EditText and ImageView is not visible).

Comment: try the code provided above.... draw `EditText` and `ImageView` in initialise method as added in on click. you also need to store how many Editext+Imageview you have in sharedpreference to draw that many.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have tried your code but It is not working.

Comment: You are using `if(many<=10)` which is wrong.... there should be a `while`. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I can't spoon feed everything... have given you hint how to proceed. check your code carefully. there might be some small error you are making.